# How to I achieve ViewPager (next/previous) in Music player App

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-music-player

I want to know how I can achieve next and previous using swipe via a view pager. The final result I want is the one that Google Play Music has. I have uploaded a picture of what my app is behaving like and also what I expect. I basically cannot get my ViewPager to show me previews of the next and previous tracks. Can anyone please help me with how I can populate the view pager with pages of the tracks I want to play hence achieving that Google play music next/previous swipe in their music playback screen.

[image: The image on the Left is google play music and on the right is my music player app.]

```
 public class PlayPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    final String POSITION = "position";
    Context mContext;

    public PlayPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,Context context) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = new FragmentNowPlaying();
        Log.e("CHASE MUSIC","The get Item position is " + position);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(POSITION, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {


        mApp = (Common) mContext.getApplicationContext();


        try {
            if (mApp.getService().getQueue().length !=0 ) {
                return mApp.getService().getQueue().length;
            } else {
                mApp.getService().stopSelf();
                return 0;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }


    }

}
```

Okay now below I have added the code from the fragment particularly code that has the position value from the Fragment Adapter. Please note that the service does most of the heavy lifting i.e Songs from the queue,next,previous,pause,play are all handled by the service.

```
 public void updateTrackInfo() {

    songPosition = getArguments().getInt(POSITION);
    Log.e("Chase Music SongPos","Song Position is: "+ songPosition);

    if (mService == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        long songid = songPosition;
            ((View) mArtistName.getParent()).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((View) mAlbumName.getParent()).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String artistName = mService.getArtistName();
            if (MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING.equals(artistName)) {
                artistName = getString(R.string.unknown_artist_name);
            }
            mArtistName.setText(artistName);

            String albumName = mService.getAlbumName();
            long albumid = mService.getAlbumId();
            if (MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING.equals(albumName)) {
                albumName = getString(R.string.unknown_album_name);
                albumid = -1;
            }
            mAlbumName.setText(albumName);
            mSongName.setText(mService.getTrackName());
            mAlbumArtHandler.removeMessages(GET_ALBUM_ART);
            mAlbumArtHandler.obtainMessage(GET_ALBUM_ART, new AlbumSongIdWrapper(albumid, songid)).sendToTarget();
            mCoverArt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mDuration = mService.duration();
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        getActivity().finish();
    }
}
```

I call the above method in onActivityCreated().

Comment: Hmm, is this because its potentially an activity right now and google plays might be a fragment? Difference between a full switch to a light switch?

Comment: Share code of view pager adapter.

Comment: The only explanation is that the second image was not applied yet, you need to probably start the loading/application of the next image either on drag or when the actual grid is created/ready.

Comment: @AshleyAlvarado I do use a fragment in my View Pager ... I have edited my post to contain the  View pager adapter code.

Comment: @NomanRafique I have edited my code to include the View Pager Adapter Code,

Comment: @JoxTraex Umm I don't quite get how I would do that.

Comment: Why are you passing `POSITION` to the fragment?

Comment: Well I'm passing in the current adapter's position into the fragment so that the fragment can populate the respective song data. **POSITION** is a string key, `position` is the value

Comment: Adapter code looks ok for me - probably you have problem with fragment creation/loading - please post it also.

Comment: Yes it looks fine. Post fragment code as well. Also give it a try `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3)`. So 3 off screen pages will be loaded.

Comment: I have set an offscreen page limit but still no change , let me share the code for the fragment, particularly where I use the position from the ViewPager @piotrpo

Comment: @NomanRafique I have tried that , still no change.